# How to get correct response from SOAP in Android?

Tags: android, xml, soap, wsdl, response

I am beginner in Android, and i am stuck here for quite some time...

MY PROBLEM: that is the response i get,  not the xml file that is expected but this:

```
## &lt;xs:element name="dsKurs" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"&gt;
  &lt;xs:complexType&gt;
    &lt;xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"&gt;
       &lt;xs:element name="KursZbir"&gt;
        &lt;xs:complexType&gt;
           &lt;xs:sequence&gt;
             &lt;xs:element name="RBr" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
             &lt;xs:element name="Datum" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
             &lt;xs:element name="Valuta" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
             &lt;xs:element name="Oznaka" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
             &lt;xs:element name="Drzava" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
            &lt;xs:element name="Nomin" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
             &lt;xs:element name="Sreden" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
             &lt;xs:element name="DrzavaAng" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
            &lt;xs:element name="NazivMak" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
             &lt;xs:element name="NazivAng" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
             &lt;xs:element name="Datum_f" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" /&gt;
           &lt;/xs:sequence&gt;
         &lt;/xs:complexType&gt;
      &lt;/xs:element&gt;
    &lt;/xs:choice&gt;
   &lt;/xs:complexType&gt;
 &lt;/xs:element&gt;
```

</xs:schema>
 </dsKurs>
 ##

Here is some my code:

```
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.nbrm.mk/klservice/GetExchangeRateD";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://www.nbrm.mk/klservice/";
private static String METHOD_NAME_SUM = "GetExchangeRateDResponse";
private static String URL = "http://www.nbrm.mk/klservice/kurs.asmx?WSDL";

public class LoadTaskj extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String StartDate, EndDate = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        StartDate = sum1.getText().toString();
        EndDate = sum2.getText().toString();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_SUM);
        request.addProperty("StartDate", StartDate);
        request.addProperty("EndDate", EndDate);
        // Use this to add parameters

        // Declare the version of the SOAP request
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        // Needed to make the internet call
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {

            androidHttpTransport
                    .setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            // String ss=androidHttpTransport.requestDump;

            // System.out.println(ss);
            // t.setText(ss);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SoapObject result = null;
        if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
            String str = ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
            Log.i("WS 1", str);

            // Another way to travers through the SoapFault object
        } else {

            try {
                Object resi = envelope.getResponse();
                SoapPrimitive resultce = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                        .getResponse();

                if (resultce != null) {
                    // resultce=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

                    Log.i("loook at mee", String.valueOf(resultce));

                }

            } catch (SoapFault e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // od poc kod
            result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            Log.d("WS", String.valueOf(result));
            // od poc kod

            String requestString = androidHttpTransport.requestDump;
            Log.d("Request in XML", requestString);
            String response1 = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
            Log.d("Response in XML", response1);

        }

        // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.

        String resultString = "";
        if (result != null) {
            resultString = result.getProperty(0).toString();

        }
        return resultString;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // String callService = callService(firstSum, secondSum);
        // t.setText(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Here is the link the POST response and request :
http://www.nbrm.mk/klservice/kurs.asmx?op=GetExchangeRateD

Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Please help me. 
For more information see: http://www.nbrm.mk/klservice/kurs.asmx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im sure but you might want to change your

```
private static String METHOD_NAME_SUM = "GetExchangeRateDResponse";
```

to

```
private static String METHOD_NAME_SUM = "GetExchangeRate";
```

and specify a start and end date.

Comment: Thank you for the answer... Even like that, i get the same response as before... I edited the question and added the links to the SOAP response and requset.

Comment: @strawberry you could try using an online soap tester: http://wsdlbrowser.com/ that always helps me. When i tested using the method "GetExchangeRate" in this, with start and end dates, it returns data that may be what you are wanting.

Comment: The METHOD_NAME is as you said, but also the url was http://www.nbrm.mk/klservice/kurs.asmx?kurs , not the one i was using.  Question, answered thank you again you've helped me so much!